# Is it possible to use <input type="file"> just to post the filename without actually uploading the file?

Tags: html, forms, upload

Ok I really didn't know how else to sum it up for the title. I need to create a form where a user can specify an existing file, but I don't need to upload it (it's on a shared server already accessible) -- I just need to grab the filename and save it in the database so it's linked to other data.

I thought about the input tag as it provides a convenient already done interface to the user's filesystem, but I don't know if it's possible to use it without the acutal upload (leaving out `enctype="multipart/form-data"` doesn't seem to work). Can I tweak this to make it work, or is there any way to do it other than writing a custom mini file browser?

EDIT: I need the full path name of the file, asking the users to enter it is out of the question...

Comment: You will not get the full path name, as this is irrelevant from the web servers point of view.

Comment: You can only get the filename, not full path. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027276/show-selected-file-without-postback/2027301#2027301

Comment: I'm also fairly certain that the HTML spec doesn't even guarantee you'll even get a filename, though most browsers will pass it in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could place the `<input type="file">` outside your HTML form, and then use the `onChange` event to fill an `<input type="hidden">` within the form that gets posted:

```
<input type="file" 
       onchange="document.getElementById('hidden_file').value = this.value;" />

<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_file" value="" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is brilliant, but is there really no way of retrieving the full path too?

Comment: Unfortunately: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676035/cant-get-the-complete-address-while-uploading-a-file, but you may want to investigate further: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81180/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-html-input-form-in-firefox-3